# floating point precision causes problems in Shapely interpolate method

Tags: python, shapely

I am trying to cut a simple linestring into 10 pieces using the shapely `cut` function described in their [docs](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html):

```
def cut(line, distance):
# Cuts a line in two at a distance from its starting point
if distance <= 0.0 or distance >= line.length:
    return [shapely.geometry.LineString(line)]
coords = list(line.coords)
for i, p in enumerate(coords):
    pd = line.project(shapely.geometry.Point(p))
    if pd == distance:
        return [
            shapely.geometry.LineString(coords[:i+1]),
            shapely.geometry.LineString(coords[i:])]
    if pd > distance:
        cp = line.interpolate(distance)
        return [
            shapely.geometry.LineString(coords[:i] + [(cp.x, cp.y)]),
            shapely.geometry.LineString([(cp.x, cp.y)] + coords[i:])]
```

I use another function to call the above function, since the `cut` function only cuts a line into two segments based on the interpolated point:

```
def split_linestring(linestring, split_length):
    #cuts a linestring in length/split_length number of segments
    length = linestring.length
    result_list = []
    if length>split_length:
        while length > split_length:
            two_segment_list = cut(linestring,split_length)
            length = two_segment_list[1].length
            result_list.append(two_segment_list[0])
            #print two_segment_list[0].length
            linestring = two_segment_list[1]
        result_list.append(two_segment_list[1])
    else:
        result_list.append(linestring)
    return result_list
```

I wrote the following small test to check the output list of linestring objects and their respective lengths:

```
A = shapely.geometry.Point(0, 0)
B = shapely.geometry.Point(2, 0)
AB = shapely.geometry.LineString([A, B])
split_length =Decimal('0.2')
#split_length = 0.2
r = split_linestring(AB, split_length)

for item in r:
    print item.length
```

The output list looks ok but the last linestring is near zero length:

```
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
2.22044604925e-16
```

I am suspecting that this is rounding error, but it is very difficult to track where or why. How can I get shapely to divide my line into 10 equal sections with no trailing near-zero linestrings?

Comment: The error comes from the system using floating point values. And it is impossible to describe `0.2` with the floating point representation used in (virtually all) computer systems. In fact `0.2` will be represented as a value slightly too small. Therefore, when cutting mutliple times, there will be a small bit remaining at the end. It seem, it does not help to use `Decimal('0.2')`, as I suppose that this is turned into floating point somewhere in the `shapely` code.

Comment: So how can I avoid this problem? Do I need to rethink the entire algorithm?

Comment: It depends on what precission you are after and what your requirements are. One thing you can do, is to detect that the last part is very small and just not cut. This will work when you are cutting a relative small initial distance as this, but it will lead to problems if your original segment is very long. Otherwise, if you know that you are cutting into 10 pieces, you can start by calculating your 9 cuts and then apply them instead of cutting from one side.